# PyOpenGL Constant Size 2D Labels for 3D Objects

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I'm trying to make labels for some 3d objects, with an icon/triangle to show you where the object is, plus some text describing what the object is.
Essentially, I want to 1. display text using pyopengl and 2. have the text + icon stay at a constant size on the screen that can 3. still move around the screen.

(I looked around a bit and looked at orthographic projections, but I'm not sure that's what I should be using...)

I have not used opengl very much at all, so this might be a dumb question!
Any help is much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

A nice start would be to store your icon + text inside a quad.
There are plenty of good tutorials on "font rendering" which will help you to create the desired quad.

You can load your icon inside a openGL texture, once done you will have to create your quad and associate a vertex and fragment shader to it. The difficult part will be to set a fixed position to your quad, that won't be linked to your 3D scene.

In video-games when you want to draw the ui, or the hud (healthbar, minimap), you draw them at the end on top off everything. Thoose elements don't need the mvp matrices, or projection matrices you might be familiar with. All the magic will appen in the vertex shader, he will be responsible to to set the position of all your elements, the output of the vertex shader should be in the [-1, 1] range for all coordinates:

- -1 -> left, top, near
- 1 -> right, bottom, far

We call this space ndc see diagram https://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html

Your job will be to output values in this range. If you want your quad to be half the size of the width and a quarter of the height, centered in the middle, you can store this information in the vertices you sent to your shader.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {-0.5, -0.25, 0, // bottom left corner
                      -0.5,  0.25, 0, // top left corner
                       0.5,  0.25, 0, // top right corner  
                       0.5, -0.25, 0}; // bottom right corner
```

vertex shader, people might use pixel size quads with a ortho projection

```
in vec3 pos;
in vec2 uv;

out fuv;

void main()
{
    //glm::mat4 translation = uTranslation might need to mvoe the quad on screen at runtime
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, -1.0, 1.0); //set it to near plane -1
    fuv = uv;
}
```

fragment shader

```
in vec2 fuv;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D renderedTexture;

void main(){
    color = texture(renderedTexture, fuv);
}
```